# Writing a matrix over two lines

Tags: matrices

I want to write a big matrix and I want to write it in two lines like the picture but I cannot find the way![image]

Comment: Oh no.... well ok, I'm calm.10..9..8..7.. factorize tilde d1 d2 d3 d4 with a diagonal matrix from the right for a start..3..2..1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\def\mtrm#1{\rule{#1}{1.5ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\bar{L}_2 = \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    \mtrm{15ex} & \mtrm{15ex}\\ 
    \mtrm{7ex}  & \mtrm{7ex} \\ 
    \mtrm{4ex}  & \mtrm{4ex} \\ 
    \mtrm{18ex} & \mtrm{18ex}\\
  \end{matrix}\right.                
\\
  \left.
  \begin{matrix}
    \mtrm{16ex} & \mtrm{6ex} \\ 
    0           & 0          \\ 
    \mtrm{4ex}  & \mtrm{14ex}\\ 
    \mtrm{19ex} & \mtrm{19ex}
  \end{matrix}\right)
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

One can also use `\substack`:

[image]

Notes:

- The matrix used here is from [I want to write an element of a matrix on two lines is possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444374/4301).
- Corrected use of `\sin`, `\cos` and defined a macro for the font selection.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\MyFont}[1]{\textrm{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont #1}}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$\tilde{A}_{Long}=\begin{pmatrix}
X_{\MyFont{u}}&X_{\MyFont{w}}&X_q-M_{33}\MyFont{w}_0&-(mg-B_u)\cos(\theta_0)\\[1.0ex]
Z_{\MyFont{u}}&Z_{\MyFont{w}}&Z_q-M_{11}\MyFont{u}_0&-(mg-B_u)\sin(\theta_0)\\[1.0ex]
M_{\MyFont{u}}&M_{\MyFont{w}}
    &\substack{M_{q}-M_{11}.x_G\MyFont{u}_0 \\ -M_{33}.z_G\MyFont{w}_0}
    &\substack{\hphantom{-}(x_Gmg+x_BB_u)\sin(\theta_{0})\\ -(z_Gmg+z_BB_u) \cos(\theta_{0})} 
    \\[1.0ex]
 0&0&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for your excellent answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        $L=$ & $\left( \begin{tabular}{c}A\\B\\C\\D\\\end{tabular} \right.$ & $\begin{tabular}{c}E\\F\\G\\H\\\end{tabular}$ \\
        & $\begin{tabular}{c}I\\J\\K\\L\\\end{tabular}$ & $\left. \begin{tabular}{c}M\\N\\O\\P\\\end{tabular} \right)$\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way, with a stacked TABstack.  Things to note:  the `\kern` will shift the top and bottom horizontally relative to each other; the `[12pt]` optional argument of `\stackanchor` is the vertical spacing between top and bottom halves; the 2ex `\setstacktabbedgap` is the horizontal gap between matrix columns; if you wanted the equation number in a different vertical location, let me know, so that I can address that.

I will leave you to replace the rules with your math terms.  They do **NOT** need to be enclosed in `$` delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\def\mtrm#1{\protect\rule{#1}{1.5ex}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setstacktabbedgap{2ex}
\def\stackalignment{r}
\stackanchor[12pt]{%
  \bar{L}_2 = \left(
  \tabbedCenterstack[c]{%
    \mtrm{10ex} & \mtrm{10ex} \\ 
    \mtrm{7ex} & \mtrm{7ex} \\ 
    \mtrm{4ex} & \mtrm{4ex} \\ 
    \mtrm{8ex} & \mtrm{8ex}
  }%
  \right.\kern2ex
}{
  \left.
  \tabbedCenterstack[c]{%
    \mtrm{6ex} & \mtrm{6ex} \\ 
    0 & 0 \\ 
    \mtrm{4ex} & \mtrm{4ex} \\ 
    \mtrm{9ex} & \mtrm{9ex}
  }%
  \right)%
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work!   LaTeX Error: File `tabstackengine.sty' not found. Should I download it separately?

Comment: @Farzane It is a recent package.  It can be found at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine.  Placing the .sty file in your current directory will work (until you figure out where to install it permanently).  The .pdf file gives documentation, though I would recommend also reading the docs for `stackengine` as well, since the latter builds on the former.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\def\mtrm#1{\protect\rule{#1}{1.5ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \bar{L}_2 = 
\begin{NiceMatrix}[baseline = line-3,margin]
    \mtrm{10ex} & \mtrm{10ex} \\ 
    \mtrm{7ex}  & \mtrm{7ex} \\ 
    \mtrm{4ex}  & \mtrm{4ex} \\ 
    \mtrm{8ex}  & \mtrm{8ex} \\
                & \mtrm{6ex} & \mtrm{6ex} \\ 
                & 0 & 0 \\ 
                & \mtrm{4ex} & \mtrm{4ex} \\ 
                & \mtrm{9ex} & \mtrm{9ex} \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix{(}{1-1}{4-2}{.}
  \SubMatrix{.}{5-2}{8-3}{)}
\end{NiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]