# I want to write an element of a matrix on two lines is possible?

Tags: matrices

I want to write an element of a matrix on two lines is possible ???
I have an element of a matrix that is too long I want to write it on 2 lines.
Thank you

```
$\tilde{A}_{Long}=\left(\begin{matrix}
X_{\textrm{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont u}}}&X_{\textrm{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont w}}}&X_q-M_{33}\textrm{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont w}}_0&-(mg-B_u)cos(\theta_0)\\
Z_{\textrm{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont u}}}&Z_{\textrm{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont w}}}&Z_q-M_{11}\textrm{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont u}}_0&-(mg-B_u)sin(\theta_0)\\
M_{\textrm{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont u}}}&M_{\textrm{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont w}}}&M_{q}-M_{11}.x_G\textrm{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont u}}_0-M_{33}.z_G\textrm{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont w}}_0&(x_Gmg+x_BB_u)sin(\theta_{0})-(z_Gmg+z_BB_u) cos(\theta_{0})\\
 0&0&1&0\\
\end{matrix}\right)$
```

Comment: you really should define your math font setup so you don't have to have `\textrm{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont u}}` in every cell (or in fact anywhere) upright italic?

Comment: never use math italic for multiletter operators, `\sin` not `sin`

Comment: @Elyes: You can also use `\substack`. I have posted an answer at the duplicate question using your matrix.